# Access an internal network Webcam from outside (www)?

Tags: networking, webserver, url

we have a webcam installed in our internal network.

I wrote a JavaScript in a HTML-File, which gives access to the stream through a BaseURL. I put it on our webserver, which is online (www). When I access the access the page through our internal network, it works of course and I can see the livestream.

If I access the website from my mobile phone (not in the network), the website loaded, but I don't see the livestream, because it is a webpage-url in our internal network.

I tried rewrite on the apache, but i think this is not the right way.

Has anyone an idea how to access the livestream of the camera?

Comment: I think maybe the video stream link in the website uses relative link, so it fails when accessed from a different domain, you need to provide a little bit more technical info to be able to tell exactly what is happening.

Comment: You need mod_proxy, not rewrite. I'd highly recommend finding someone who knows what they're doing to help you before you expose your entire internal network to the Internet, or become an open relay.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed similar problem with my webcam using [momentcam](http://momentcamparapc.com/descargar-momentcam-para-pc-gratis/) try to uninstall or reinstall the software.